# using a dictionary of string and interface in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I have an Interface called as IObSrc, I have few classes that implement this interface called as ObSrc1, ObScr2 etc..

```
Interface IObSrc
{
  string id;
}
```

I also have an interface called as IDtSrc, this interface inturn is implemented by a few classes called as DtSrc1, DtSrc2.

```
Interface IDtSrc
{
  IObSrc getObject();
  Dictionary<string,IObSrc> getObjects();
}
```

When i implement this interface from DtSrc1, and I return ObSrc1 from DtSrc1, there is no issue, but when i return `Dictionary<string,ObSrc1>` or `Dictionary<string,ObSrc2>`, i get an indication of typemismatch.

```
public class DtSrc : IDtSrc
{
  public Dictionary<string,IObSrc> getObjects()
  {
    Dictionary<string,ObSrc1> val1 = new ...'
    ...
    return val1;
  }

}
```

How can i solve this issue.

*** EDITED ***

I have one more query, what if a method should return a generic type that can be varied by the implementation.

**Example**:

```
interface IDtSrc<T> where T:IObSrc
{ 
  T ExecuteObject(string objId);
}
```

This will be used as

```
class DtSrc1 
{ 
  string ExecuteObject(string objId)
  {..}
}
```

and

```
class DtSrc2
{ 
 Dictionary<string,string> ExecuteObject(string objId)
 {..}
}
```

Kindly suggest a right procedure for this also.

Comment: Are these truly indicative of your interface/class names? If so, please do yourselves and other developers a favor and completely spell out the names, such as `IDataSource`. There's no need to have abbreviated names in the current landscape.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram like SqlCommand and DbCommand for example...

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich: `Sql` is a well known and accepted abbreviation (like `Html`). `Db` can be argued about. But leaving out all vowels is just plain evil.

Comment: @ChrisWue no argument, I'm just saying there are reasons for doing it. I would have spelled it out too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use generics with a constraint

```
interface IDtSrc<T> where T:IObSrc
{
  IObSrc getObject();
  Dictionary<string,T> getObjects();
}
```

But your implementation of `IDtSrc` will only be able to return one type of `IObSrc`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it worked fine. Further, I have started the implementation, i have one more query, what if a method should return a generic type that can be varied by the implementation. Example: `interface IDtSrc<T> where T:IObSrc{ T ExecuteObject(string objId);}`. This will be used as class DtSrc1 { string ExecuteObject(string objId){..}}` and `class DtSrc2{ Dictionary<string,string> ExecuteObject(string objId){..}}`. Kindly suggest a right procedure for this also.

Answer (score 6):

If you declare a dictionary of type `Dictionary<string,IObSrc>`, then you cannot substitute a dictionary with type parameters that are different in any way, even if the new type parameters inherit from the original.  That's why `Dictionary<string, ObSrc1>` and `Dictionary<string, ObSrc2>` are failing.

What you're trying to achieve is called type covariance, and it's not supported on `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.  Type covariance is only supported on collections which are "read only"—namely `IEnumerable<T>`.

It may seem silly, but consider what could happen otherwise:

```
Dictionary<string, IObSrc> dict = new Dictionary<string, ObSrc1>(); //illegal
dict.Add("X", new Obsrc2());
```

If this were allowed, the second line would compile fine, but blow up at runtime.

Comment: He named the concrete implementations `ObSrc1` and `ObSrc2` not `IObSrc1` etc. I gets a bit confusing reading your answer.

Comment: @AdamRackis: Thanks for the explanation Adam & ChrisWue. I am planning to tryout the alternative suggested by Yuriy.